# git update production server cause no such file or directory error

Tags: git

I have simple git workflow of PHP application, and it works almost perfect: on "git push" from staging server I'm getting webhook request to production, and run "git pull" or "git fetch --all; git reset --hard origin master" - and production correctly updates application. 
However in some rare cases, probably under heavy server loads, I'm getting one-two "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory" errors from Apache/PHP during this update procedure.

The question is how to correctly mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens when some folders or files your system expects to exist no longer exist. The absolute best would be to run these commands when file structure is not going to change. Alternatively, you can write a software which does the necessary attempt and in case of a failure waits for 5 minutes and tries again. You should make also sure that the files and folders you do not need to be versioning are inside .gitignore. If these problems are occurring due to frequent changes on files, because users are uploading some profile pictures, for example, then you might want to avoid versioning user profile pictures.

Comment: well, this happens when Apache/PHP requests .php files, and these files were updated during "git pull". E.g. file `/var/www/html/proj/file.php` was in previous git release and had some changes in new release, changes usually merged. And I see errors in PHP like "Warning: require_once(/var/www/.../file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" exactly when running `git pull`.
I thought to use "blue-green" deployment, but it will be much slower than just git pull, and could cause logical issues because old web server and new server will run simultaneously for several minutes.

Comment: This is because you are doing this while the files are being changed. If this is bothering you, then you can do it by avoiding collisions between your git pull and file changes. You can shut down the application temporarily, for instance. Or create a separate repo where changes are not se frequent.

Comment: indeed, and because of this I run updates in night-time usually. Is there maybe some git switch/option to update files in atomic operation during git pull (*nix mv/rename supposed to be atomic), or could it be filesystem cache issue?

Comment: @user3037511 do you use page caching?